# Laravel 5 - Checking if a user has 'voted' when returning all votes for the resource as a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am making a voting system for a link sharing website I am working on.

When a user votes on a link as a new row is added to the db with the link id and user id.

When showing these links in my controller I call a relationship (votes):

```
$links = Link::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with('votes')->paginate(20);
```

And the relationship in the model

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\LinkVote');
}
```

In my view I am running a foreach on the $links to display each one. My aim is to show a different button if the user has already voted for that link.

When dd'ing $link->votes I get:

[image]

How can I check (in my view and in the foreach) if the currently logged in user is in that array of votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains):

```
$link->votes->contains('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
```

Or [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) with [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count):

```
if ($link->votes->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count()) {
```

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than I was planning in my head!